# Users are not able to run stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure which runs perfectly from the server, but other users are not able to run it.

As a test I added one user and granted the user for the procedure. But still no luck.

What am I missing?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [D40\GBH463].[CustOrdersOrders2] 
    @Param1 varchar(20),
    @Param2 varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testtabel (waarde1, waarde2) 
    VALUES (@Param1, @Param2);
END
```

Comment: What do you mean by " not able to run it"?  Does it use dynamic SQL?

Comment: Do you get permission denied error or SP does not exist?  That it is permissions issue and you need to grant them access/permissions to run it.

Comment: Yes, this is the procedure :

Comment: BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.

    insert into  testtabel (waarde1,waarde2) values ( 
 @Param1, @Param2);
END

Comment: Another user gets the message the procedure is not existing

Comment: Did you grant execute permissions on the proc to the user (`GRANT EXECUTE ON [D40\GBH463].[CustOrdersOrders2] TO YourUser;`)?

Comment: you will have to provide the required Grants on this proc to the user/env

Comment: I did, what is the difference between 'Grant'and 'With Grant'?

Comment: Grant allows execution. With Grant allows extending permission to other users.